# Getting a great Video message Thread in IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, instant-messaging

I'm trying to achieve something like the below

[image]

Essentially i will need to have a single UIView that holds these objects one being the video from the user who posted and a reply function for a user to record and play back.
The hard part for me is trying to get it to function similar to a message feed.

How could i approach designing this UIView so that i can have all the controls i need from `MPMoviePlayerControl` in one view for both recording and viewing the video?

Comment: This question is too broad, vague, and opinion based. Either one of those three makes it off-topic. Please redo this question so it is appropriate to SO.

Comment: This question is too broad, vague, and opinion based. Either one of these three makes it off-topic. Please redo this question so it is appropriate to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Paulo, top half can be webView where video can be displayed. Also this can be AVPlayer(or AVPlayerLayer). Bottom half should use AVFoundation for image capture. That way you can have custom capture interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your top half can use a subview with a UIWebview to run the videos from  video sites like youtube. To capture video is more problematic Apple class UIImagepickerController will require fullscreen in iPhone and a popup window in iPads so the design you showed here is not workable unless you have a 3rd party video picker that can override Apple constraints. My suggestion is to just float a video record button (or use gestures) over a full screen UIWebview,